# Define local variable in docker-compose.yml?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is it possible to define local variable in docker-compose.yml?

Something like this for example:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: $APP_NAME
    container_name: $APP_NAME
```

Can I define the value of `$APP_NAME` on this same `docker-compose.yml` file?

Comment: Would [environment variables](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/) fill your need?

Comment: @zero298 Well yeah, I'm aware of those but I'm looking specifically if "local" is possible so I don't have to do it the env way.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Starting from docker-compose file version 3.4, you can define a top level `x-` prefixed section in the compose file. It will be parsed as valid yml but ignored by compose when creating services, network, volumes, etc...

```
version: '3.4'

x-var: &APP_NAME
  myimage

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: *APP_NAME
    container_name: *APP_NAME
```

You can even use this feature to define "object", like:

```
x-common: &common
  image: ${REGISTRY_URL}img:latest

services:
  master:
    <<: *common
```

Comment: This appears to work but how do you "concatenate" hard values? e.g., This would cause an error `container_name: "*APP_NAME-extra-value"` or `- "/var/www/*APP_NAME/:/srv/app/"`

Comment: Well I believe you can only concatenate before the `anchor`, anyway this is not the intended usage of this feature.